# Error using built version of Dojo (but not the uncompressed source)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I noticed something weird when using the uncompressed source of Dojo our code runs normally without error. I tried these two from the archives so far

dojo-release-1.10.6-src and dojo-release-1.10.8-src

However when I switch to the built versions, either

dojo-release-1.10.6 or dojo-release-1.10.8

There is an error that occurs when using dojo.query

> TypeError: root.getElementsByTagName is not a function

My function call looks like this

```
var dom_frag = domConstruct.toDom(response);
var title = dojo.query(".accordion_title", dom_frag)[0];
```

where response contains HTML string. (too long to post here)

**EDIT**: Image of debugger showing contents of 'dom_frag'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether `response` has been correctly converted to DOM using built dojo versions? (Like `console.log(dom_frag)`) Consider also replacing deprecated `dojo.query` with requiring `dojo/query` [module](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html#usage)

Comment: @barbsan added image to show it got converted to document fragment successfully, will try the dojo/query, thanks

Comment: @barbsan using dojo/query has no effect - same error, although how do you know dojo.query is depreciated?

Comment: See first tip in [tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modern_dojo/index.html#hello-new-world). (Of course changing this couldn't help - it behave same way for backward compability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, have you checked to see if the dom_frag variable is a single dom node? If the dom fragment is multiple nodes, then the dojo.query won't work, because it needs to search the children of a single dom node.
To solve this, try wrapping the toDom contents with a single node... like so:

```
var dom_frag = domConstruct.toDom("<div>"+response+"</div>");
var title = dojo.query(".accordion_title", dom_frag)[0];
```

This is, of course, a bit of a hack... but if you can't guarantee that the response will end up a single node, then you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `root` is actually a DOM element as:

> the Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The subtree
>   underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element
>   itself. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: Not really, it can be called on any HTML element. See at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)